# File is not found when I try to upload the files to S3 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm following a simple tutorial on YouTube about how to automatically upload files in S3 using Python, and I'm getting this error shows that:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'age.csv'
```

And this does not make sense to me, because files are there. For example, this my code looks like:

```
client = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                      aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)

path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/projects/AWS-Data-Processing/example_data'

for file in os.listdir(path):
    upload_file_bucket = 'my-uploaded-data'
    print(file)
    if '.txt' in file:
        upload_file_key_txt = 'txt/' + str(file)
        client.upload_file(file, upload_file_bucket, upload_file_key_txt)
        print("txt")
    elif '.csv' in file:
        upload_file_key_csv = 'csv/' + str(file)
        client.upload_file(file, upload_file_bucket, upload_file_key_csv)
        print("csv")
```

And when I comment out the part where it says:

```
client.upload_file(file, upload_file_bucket, upload_file_key_txt)
```

it prints out either "txt" or "cvs", and I comment out to just read files such as:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    upload_file_bucket = 'my-uploaded-data'
    print(file)
```

Then it successfully prints out the file names. So I don't understand why I get the error of there is no file existing when there is. It sounds contradicting and I need some help to understand this error.
I read a post where I might need to download AWS CLI, so which I did but it didn't help. I'm guessing the problem lies in the function `upload_file` but I just don't understand how there is no file?
Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `upload_file` function takes a full file **path**, and not just a name. It cannot guess what is your directory, so you need to prepend it or use a different way of iterating over the files.

Source: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

Comment: Sorry, but can you elaborate on what does "takes a full file path" mean? Does this mean that upload_file is like searching for the files in my entire computer, rather than the path I specified?

Comment: You supplied only `age.csv` to the `upload_file` function. It can never know _which_ file exactly you are talking about. What if you have one in Documents, one in Desktop and one in Downloads? That's why you should supply the exact location of the file, for example: `C:/Users/User/Desktop/python/projects/AWS-Data-Processing/example_data/age.csv`.

Comment: In other words - upload `path + file`, not just `file`.

Comment: Exactly. You could do `.upload_file(f'{path}/file')`. Also, I'd actually rename `file` to `file_name` as this is what it really is. Definitely not a file object.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what it means now. Can't believe it took me a day to know this......

Comment: Hey @here is there a way of dynamically getting path from where user uploads. Case scenario  User one uploads from Documents folder User2 Uploads from Downloads . How can it get this path in my python mind guiding?